# Don't work correctly script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

I need to get interface by number. My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

interfaces=/root/tt
interfaces_with_numbers=/root/tt2

ls -1 /sys/class/net > /root/tt
cat -n $interfaces > $interfaces_with_numbers
cat $interfaces_with_numbers

read number
echo $number

eth=`cat $interfaces_with_numbers | grep $number | awk '{ print $2 }'`

if [[ -d /sys/class/net/$eth ]];then
    echo "You choose is: $eth"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

I have output:

```
 1  dummy0
 2  eno1
 3  enp4s0
 4  lo
 5  virbr0
 6  virbr0-nic
```

It is simply text file with spaces. Ok. Script has asked, what i want to enter. I entered "2". It is working – In result, i get name of interface. I entered "1", and i have "not found". I have written in linux command line:

```
cat tt2 | grep 1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

And i have got the output:

```
dummy0
eno1
```

How to do this script correct ? Please help. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending which interface you select, grep may be finding multiple answers. For example, selecting menu item #1 will cause grep to find both `1 dummy0` and `2 eno1`. This results in two results being returned from grep which are separated by a newline character. eg:

`eth='dummmy0
eno1'`

when `-d` tries to evaluate `eth`, it tries to eval the entire variable, including the carriage return, and the statement obviously returns false. Try to use egrep with a regex for a fix. `^\s+$number` will look only at the beginning of the line for a match. the `\s+` will account for tabs or other whitespace prefixing the number:

```
eth=`cat $interfaces_with_numbers | egrep "^\s+$number" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` to check matching condition exactly:

```
eth=`awk "(\$1==$number) { print \$2 }" $interfaces_with_numbers`
```